# How to disable verbose print statements when using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, suppress-warnings

When I run my code using tensorflow==1.9.0 I get the following print statements. These are the first of a couple of hundred print statements. The rest of the statements are similar to these ones. How get I disable all print statements from tensorflow?

```
Device mapping: no known devices.
truncated_normal/TruncatedNormal: (TruncatedNormal): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
truncated_normal/mul: (Mul): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
truncated_normal: (Add): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Variable: (VariableV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Variable/Assign: (Assign): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Variable/read: (Identity): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Variable_1: (VariableV2): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
Variable_1/Assign: (Assign): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0
```

I have already tried

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
```

as mentioned in other posts.

Answer (score 0):

Set `config.log_device_placement = False` in `tf.ConfigProto()` instance that you use for `tf.Session`.